# How to remove duplicate results from a cts:uris when distinct values does not work

Tags: duplicates, xquery, marklogic

I have the following code that returns an array of array of results I try to use distinct-values to remove duplicates and it does nothing I have tried also removing using looping functions by comparing values with no success.

I have tried converting to "xs anyAtomicType" and using distinct values
I have tried putting in json array and extracting the sub-array 
I have tried tokenizing, xdmp quote, string-before/after and many others

```
declare function local:verify-user-uri($dir as xs:string) 
{ 
   for $each in cts:uris($dir, ())
     let $uIds := (for $d in $each  
     where contains($d, "/profile.xml")
   return $d)

   return $uIds
};
```

I get back duplicated result in form of:

```
/users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
/users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
/users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
```

I am expecting:

```
/users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
```

Comment: Please include all of the code needed to reproduce your issue. URIs are unique across the database, so the example you have included doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have simply invoked this function 3 times and didn't realize it?

You have declared `$dir` to be a single `xs:string`. If your `$dir` happened to be a sequence of strings of the same directory, or if you otherwise invoked the function 3 times with the directory variable.

It can easily happen with function mapping enabled (default behavior). https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/enhanced#id_55459

There are a couple of things that you can do as a diagnostic:

1.) Remove the explicit type on the `$dir` parameter in the function:

```
declare function local:verify-user-uri($dir) 
{ 
   for $each in cts:uris($dir, ())
   let $uIds := (for $d in $each  
     where contains($d, "/profile.xml")
     return $d)
   return $uIds
};
```

do you get an error executing `cts:uris()` that looks like this:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: )err:XPT0004) cts:uris(("/users/", "/users/", "/users/"), ()) -- arg1 is not of type xs:string?

2.) try disabling function mapping by adding the following to the prolog:

```
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
```

and see if you then get an invalid coercion error like:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-AS (err:XPTY0004) $dir as xs:string -- Invalid coersion ("/users/", "/users/", "/users/") as xs:string

3.) You could also add something to the end of the sequence of values returned from the function to indicate how many times it has executed:

```
declare function local:verify-user-uri($dir as xs:string) 
{ 
   for $each in cts:uris($dir, ())
   let $uIds := (for $d in $each  
     where contains($d, "/profile.xml")
     return $d)
   return $uIds, "#"
};
```

And see how many times you see "#" in the result. If more than one, you are invoking the function multiple times.

Comment: thanks I will try that try the options suggestion. Sorry about the ($dir as xs:string)  I had it in code must of forgot to copy it down correctly

Comment: I tried the following and got the same result but with the end containing a # at the end multiple times as before
I know I am making only one call to the function as the string param is only dir = "/users/"

Comment: let $db := -conf:getOnlineDB()
    let $test := xdmp:eval('declare option xdmp:mapping "false"; declare variable $dir 
    as xs:string external; contains(cts:uris($dir, ()), "/profile.xml")', 
                             (xs:QName("dir"), $dir),
                             <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
                             <database>{xdmp:database($db)}</database>
                             </options>)

Comment: /users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
#
/users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
#
/users/123-343-/profile.xml
/users/122-222-/profile.xml
#

Comment: It looks like you are passing a sequence to contains; how can that work?  What about cts:uris($dir)[fn:ends-with (., '/profile.xml')

Answer (score 0):

Next to the good suggestions from Mads, I notice a couple of other things about your code:

- It doesn't make sense to iterate over `$each` as it contains one uri only. Keep in mind that a FLWOR statement ends with a return, which tells what should be the result *per item*
- Beware that the first arg to `cts:uris` only marks a start, not an end. If you feed in `/aaa/`, you also get back `/bbb/` etc, though not vice versa.

To be honest, I think you are looking for [`cts:uri-match()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uri-match) instead, which would reduce your function to a one-liner:

```
declare function local:verify-user-uri($dir as xs:string) { 
  cts:uri-match($dir || "*/profile.xml")
};
```

HTH!

PS: I do recommend always disabling function mapping as Mads recommends. It can prevent a lot of confusion.